# Java issues comparing strings in list

Tags: java, list, comparison

I am taking an intermediate Java class where we have been assigned to create a dictionary. The user would input the word and the meaning and then it would be added to the list

currently whenever a new word is added to the list it is supposed to compare itself with the other words until it finds its appropriate place. Whenever I type a new word that is before the first word it deletes the first word and puts itself there, 
whenever I put a word that should go after I get a NullPointerException. I'm not sure what's wrong

Heres the part of my code that is giving me issues:

```
    void add(Word w)
{
    WordNode temp = new WordNode(w);


    if (list == null)
        list = temp;

    else
    {
        WordNode aux = list;
                    WordNode back = null;
                    boolean found = false;
        while(aux != null && !found)
        if (temp.word.getTitle().compareTo(aux.word.getTitle()) < 0) 
                        found = true;
                    else
                    {
                        back = aux;
                        aux = aux.next;
                    }
                    aux.next = temp;
                    if (back == null)
                        list = temp;
                    else
                        back.next = temp;

    }// End of the else

}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in an IDE debugger?  What does that tell you?

Comment: I suggest you start by firing up a debugger and step through your code to see what it is doing.

Comment: A compare result of `< 0` indicates that the value is **not** equal. A result of `== 0` indicates that it is the same. Your code assumes that `< 0` means it is found. And please get some intendation + brackets going.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(aux != null && !found)
    if (temp.word.getTitle().compareTo(aux.word.getTitle()) < 0) 
                    found = true;
                else
                {
                    back = aux;
                    aux = aux.next;
                }
```

when it exits the while loop when aux is null, the next line

```
aux.next = temp;
```

would have a nullpointerexception because aux is null